# Position of 3d objects using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, 3d

The end result should look something like the picture attached ([Link to illustation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW49Y.png)).

Each part of the picture is individual png images drawn in Illustrator and each of these have their own CSS class.

My problem is how to make the position of each individual block (png) in order to make them look like this.
Which CSS attributes can I play around with to position them like this.

I realized also that they cannot be centered vertically because then they will not appear to be in the middle of each other.

I have used ng-repeat earlier to draw circles (as round div's), but then I get all the circles in only one dimension.

Any ideas how this can be done and what I need to have in mind when doing it?

```
Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/tyt4ft3g/1/
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried in a demo or a fiddle?

Comment: Sure. I tried around the browser with differnt values. But as soon as I change the size of one of the images, it start to look strange. I want o use some sort of relative position to another img based on the size etc..
https://jsfiddle.net/tyt4ft3g/1/

Comment: This seemed to be a tricky thing? No one that has some good knowledge in HTML/CSS. It is basically about positioning and what I would guess relative positioning of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have attempted is absolutely correct and is the best possible way of doing that object.

Basically you have to provide `position: absolute` to all your `img` elements and have a common `position: relative` parent. You have to position them correctly with the `right` and `bottom` properties so that each image appears on the center of its predecessor.

Also, provide a higher `z-index` to the images on top (i.e the smaller images on the left should have a higher z-index than the ones on the right in decreasing order).

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/tyt4ft3g/2/).

Refer code for a better perspective:

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.copper {
  height: 30px;
  right: 72px;
  bottom: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  content: url(http://i.imgur.com/LeIGPou.png);
}

.ins {
  height: 60px;
  right: 37px;
  bottom: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  content: url(http://i.imgur.com/3bMaW3t.png);
}

.power {
  height: 70px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  content: url(http://i.imgur.com/jFYquAI.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="copper">
  <img class="ins">
  <img class="power">
</div>
```